# SwiftUI: Value of optional type 'Binding<String>?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Binding<String>'

Tags: swift, swiftui, textfield

I am currently learning SwiftUI and trying to understand `@EnvironmentObject`, which I find a bit confusing.

I want to share a store containing some data throughout my app, so I wrote this:

```
class Store: ObservableObject {    
    @Published var user: User?    
}

class User: ObservableObject {    
    @Published var name: String?    
}
```

My app view:

```
struct AppView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store    

    var body: some View {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(store)
        }
    }    
}
```

SceneDelegate:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {    
    var window: UIWindow?        
    var store = Store()

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            let appView = AppView().environmentObject(store)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: appView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }    
}
```

And in `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Type some text here", text: $store.user?.name ?? "")
        }
    }    
}
```

However, I am getting an error on the line where I declare the `TextField`:

> Value of optional type 'Binding?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Binding'

I don't understand what this means, and don't know what to do here.

Thank you for your help

Comment: What should happen if the `User` is nil?

Comment: In your `store` your `user` is optional (adding `?`) if you want to get rid if the error remove the `?` or force unwrap it with `!`. If you force unwrap you have to check for `nil` before you load the view or you will have a crash if you have a `user = nil`

Comment: @pawello2222 Thank you for your answer. I tried to set a default value if user is nil (see edit), but still having the same error.

Comment: But "" is not a variable, it's a constant. You need to understand that what you give for `text:` is a variable that the TextField can use to _bind_ the text entered by the user to. I think you need to go back and figure out a way to make `user` non-optional in your Store type.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a possible solution for the case if both `user` and `name` variables can be `nil` - you need to use a custom binding:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var store: Store
    
    var binding: Binding<String> {
        .init(get: {
            store.user?.name ?? ""
        }, set: {
            store.user?.name = $0
        })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Type some text here", text: binding)
        }
    }
}
```

But you should rather consider displaying this `TextField` only when the `user` variable is present. Otherwise what are you really editing? It can't be the name of the user if the user is missing...

---

Alternatively, try making both these variables *non-optional* (and preferably changing `User` to *struct*):

```
class Store: ObservableObject {
    @Published var user = User(name: "test") // init here or in the `init`
}

struct User {
    var name: String // assuming that a `User` always has a `name`
}
```

and the `TextField` will work just fine:

```
TextField("Type some text here", text: $store.user.name)
```